# Edit cv making request to GET pointers.png but not there

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

When I am on **edit cv** within jobs its making a GET request to obtain an image on imageshack...but the resource isn't there.

What is pointers.png:

[image]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is because we're trying to load the content of your top answers from SO.

Your answer to [How to assign void* pointer1 to void* pointer2? Facing some problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493313/how-to-assign-void-pointer1-to-void-pointer2-facing-some-problem/2493344#2493344)
has that image in the answer!

Comment: But don't you think you should only be loading the title of the question / answer than the actual contents on a cv?  Let's face it CV's should contain headings not the actual details when it comes to a question / answer.

Comment: @JonH the API call we're using returns the whole thing. Yes, it would make more sense to load just the title and load the content on demand, and it'll likely be changed in the coming weeks, but for now it's an unnecessary change.

Comment: Ok the api call returns JSON though right?  Can you extract only what is needed?

Comment: It does indeed but I think removing the content outright is not the right approach. Again, unnecessary change at this point in time; we have big plans for CVs so minimal functional changes in that area for now.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't see why. Question asks about an unknown image and comments ask for a functionality change. It seems like a nice to have that we may never get to and only addresses the original question in an indirect way.